# Azure Machine learning python can't open file

Tags: python, azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I chose to use Python 3.8.1 Azure ML in Azure Machine learning studio, but when i run the command
`!python train.py`, it uses python Anconda 3.6.9, when i downloaded python 3.8 and run the command `!python38 train.py` in the same dir  as before, the response was `python3.8: can't open file` .
Any idea?
Also Python 3 in azure, is always busy, without anything running from my side.
Thank you.

Comment: is the the new Azure Machine Learning? Are you using a compute instance? I assume you're using a notebook? Have you tried opening a terminal, this has been an option for a few months now.

Comment: Yes, but i would like to use the notebook option as my primary. Terminal was the last choice.

Answer (score 1):

You should try adding a new Python 3.8 Kernel. Here and instructions how to add a new Kernel: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-access-terminal#add-new-kernels

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I understand your pain point, and I agree that calling bash commands in a notebook cell should execute in the same conda environment as the one associated with the selected kernel of the notebook. I think this is bug, I'll flag it to the notebook feature team, but I encourage you to open a priority support ticket if you want to ensure that your problem is addressed!